# .NET AdaptivePayment SDK: PaymentDetails() is throwing a ConnectionException (404)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am calling the `AdaptivePaymentService.PaymentDetails()` to get the payment details for a payment, and it is throwing a ConnectionException indicating 404.  In order to debug the issue, I downloaded the source for the AdaptivePayment SDK as well as the Core SDK and stepped through the code, specifically, right where the `HttpRequest` is executed in `Paypal.HttpConnection.Execute()`.

It appears as if all configuration variables are being read from the web.config:

[image]

The address in the underlying httpRequest looks correct:

[image]

The payload looks correct:

[image]

However, a WebException is thrown with the following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /cgi-bin/ppapi was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at <a href="mailto:ppmtps@paypal.com">api.sandbox.paypal.com</a> Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have configured both ClientId/Secret and 3-token credentials (API username, password, signature) in your configuration, the endpoint has been detected incorrectly, giving the REST API higher preference. Please remove the client id / secret configuration and you should see the endpoint set correctly to https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails